# Improve performance of string to binary number conversion

Tags: java, string, algorithm, binary

This is one of the questions that I faced in competitive programming.

Ques) You have an input String which is in binary format `11100` and you need to count number of steps in which number will be zero. If number is `odd -> subtract it by 1`, if `even -> divide it by 2`.

For example

28 -> 28/2

14 -> 14/2

7 -> 7-1

6 -> 6/2

3 -> 3-1

2 -> 2/2

1-> 1-1

0 -> STOP

Number of steps =7

I came up with the following solutions

```
public int solution(String S) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    String parsableString = cleanString(S);
    int integer = Integer.parseInt(S, 2);
    return stepCounter(integer);
}

private static String cleanString(String S){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < S.length() && S.charAt(i) == '0')
        i++;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(S);
    sb.replace(0,i,"");
    return sb.toString();
}

private static int stepCounter(int integer) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (integer > 0) {
        if (integer == 0)
            break;
        else {
            counter++;
            if (integer % 2 == 0)
                integer = integer / 2;
            else
                integer--;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

The solution to this question looks quite simple and straightforward, however the performance evaluation of this code got me a big ZERO. My initial impressions were that converting the string to int was a bottleneck but failed to find a better solution for this. Can anybody please point out to me the bottlenecks of this code and where it can be significantly improved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a binary number is odd, the last (least significant) digit **must be** 1, so subtracting 1 is just changing the last digit from 1 to 0 (which, importantly, makes the number even).

If a binary number is even, the last digit **must be** 0, and dividing by zero can be accomplished by simply removing that last 0 entirely. (Just like in base ten, the number 10 can be divided by ten by taking away the last 0, leaving 1.)

So the number of steps is two steps for every 1 digit, and one step for every 0 digit -- minus 1, because when you get to the last 0, you don't divide by 2 any more, you just stop.

Here's a simple JavaScript (instead of Java) solution:

```
let n = '11100';
n.length + n.replace(/0/g, '').length - 1;
```

With just a little more work, this can deal with leading zeros '0011100' properly too, if that were needed.

Answer (score 1):

Number of times you need to subtract is the number of one bits which is [`Integer.bitCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-). Number of times you need to divide is the position of most-significant bit which is [`Integer.SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#SIZE) (32, total number of bits in integer) minus [`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-int-) minus one (you don't need to divide `1`). For zero input I assume, the result should be zero. So we have

```java
int numberOfOperations = integer == 0 ? 0 : Integer.bitCount(integer) + 
  Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(integer) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the given condition, we are dividing the number by 2 if it is even which is equivalent to remove the LSB, again if number is odd we are subtracting 1 and making it an even which is equivalent to unset the set bit (changing 1 to 0). Analyzing the above process we can say that the total number of steps required will be the sum of (number of bits i.e. (log2(n) +1)) and number of set bits - 1(last 0 need not to be removed).

**C++ code:**

`result = __builtin_popcount(n) + log2(n) + 1 - 1;
 result =  __builtin_popcount(n) + log2(n);`